# Custom validation of Spring request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I've exposed a rest service that accepts `value_param` as a request parameter. If the url param is not spelt correctly then the following exception is thrown:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Sep 15 10:57:54 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'value_param' is not present
```

I'm attempting to explicitly check the parameter. This parameter check is in combination with other checks and any validation check fails, throw a 422 error.

Here is the endpoint signature:

```
   @GetMapping("/values")
    public List<ValueEntity> getValues(@RequestParam(name = "value_param") String valueParameter) {
```

How to access the `value_param` parameter and prevent the Error page with status 400 being thrown ?

Comment: You can set `@RequestParam`'s `required` attribute to false, but if it's in combination with other validation, perhaps it should be handled with a separate request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the field as `@RequestParam(required = false)`  in the controller. 
For more detailed examples could be seen: [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)

Comment: thanks, how to access the parameter name passed set by the caller of the service? So if value_param has not been set determine what parameter has been passed?

Comment: if you dont pass the the param it will be null in this case, you can also set the defaultValue = "someValue " so that can know when its passed and when its a default value;

Comment: if I pass ....?value_param_incorrect=test can I access the parameter name within the controller getValues method? In this case, the parameter name is value_param_incorrect